How can I text-to-speech all subtitle fragments at once into another language?
People. Who knows how to use CapCut? How can I text-to-speech all subtitle fragments at once into another language? CapCut allows you to automatically create subtitles for a video and then translate them into another language. CapCut then has the ability to convert each such fragment into a voice. This way, you can re-voice the video into another language. So far, I know how to re-voice each subtitle fragment separately. I select a subtitle fragment, click "Text to speech", select a voice, and it re-voices this fragment. Question: how to make it re-voice all fragments at once, all subtitles, so that I don't have to do it piece by piece? Here is a screenshot. The orange fragments above the video are text subtitles, the green fragments below the video are the voiced fragments. Thank you.

